# Insert value into unbound column in bound datagridview

Tags: winforms, datagridview, c#-3.0

I've searched. I really have and I've given up.

I have a DataGridView that is bound but it also has several unbound columns. I'm calculating the values in some of these unbound cells through values on the form including other cells that *are* bound.

I can successfully set the value of a cell, however, under no circumstances is the value being reflected on the UI.  I've checked the value on the proper cells as I exit the method and they are correct. I've tried refreshing and updating, but still nothing appears on the front end.

Can anyone tell me why the UI is not showing the values?

This is using Winforms and not WPF if it matters.

TIA

Comment: What type of DataSource are you using? DataTable, list...?

Comment: @Thomas I'm using a TableAdapter, but I managed to resolve it.  Thanks in every case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apparently am required to use the DataGridView's native events to perform such manipulation which I find to be extremely counter-intuitive. I plugged the code into the DataBindingComplete() event and boom, it worked.